# How to optimize a DjangoORM reverse foreign key query?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have the following relationships:

[image]

I'm trying to select all tasks with all instances and their vehicle. This however is a very slow query.

To my understand I have to use prefetch_related because it's a OneToMany relationship.

My InstanceModel has a reverse foreign key to Task:

`task = models.ForeignKey(TaskModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="instances")`

I've attempted a query like this in DjangoORM:

```
TaskModel.objects.filter(department_id=department_id).prefetch_related("instances", "instances__vehicle")
```

But it's very slow. Is there any way to optimize this or due the relationship inherently restrict this query pattern?

Running in Django 3.x

Comment: How many results are you fetching?

Comment: there are roughly ~30k tasks and ~60k instances

Comment: Fetching that amount of data is always going to be slow. What are you doing with the data after you fetch it?

Comment: Could you show us the result van EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query and the SQL itself? And what indexes to you have? Could you show the DDL?

Comment: @FrankHeikens sorry what dose a DDL mean?

Comment: @J.Kirk. DDL = Data Definition Language, the code that constructs your database, schemas, tables, columns, constraints, indexes, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language